# Simulate ctrl click on Richfaces3.3 rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I been try to add some checkbox to a extenddatatable.
So I'll need to simulate the ctrl-click on table rows when click on checkbox.

I tried to use:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
          e.ctrlKey = true;
          jQuery(rowToClick).trigger(e);
```

But it just never work.
And I tried to get the onRowClick event from rich:extendedDataTable,
the event.ctrlKey always "false".

```
<rich:extendedDataTable onRowClick="rowBeenclick(event);" ..../>

function rowBeenclick(e){
  debugger;
alert(e.ctrlKey);
}
```

Any idea or suggestion about that?

Comment: P.S. it works for we for Richfaces4.x, but for this I'll need in RF3.3

Comment: I just figure out my self!
Share here:(Too long so I cut to two post IE/others)

//Do ctrl click
        function fireEvent(obj,evt){

            var fireOnThis = obj;
            if(document.createEvent) {//For firefox or else
              var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
              evObj.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      true, false, false, false, 0, null);
              fireOnThis.dispatchEvent( evObj );

            }
        }

Comment: //Do ctrl click
        function fireEvent(obj,evt){

            var fireOnThis = obj;
             if(document.createEventObject) {//For IE
                var evObj = document.createEventObject();
                evObj.ctrlKey=true;
               fireOnThis.fireEvent('onclick', evObj);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out my self! Share here:(Too long so I cut to two post IE/others)

```
//Do ctrl click 
function fireEvent(obj,evt){
 var fireOnThis = obj; 
if(document.createEvent) {
//For firefox or else 
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
evObj.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false,         false, 0, null); 
fireOnThis.dispatchEvent( evObj ); } 
}
//Do ctrl click 
function fireEvent(obj,evt){
 var fireOnThis = obj; 
if(document.createEventObject) {
//For IE 
var evObj = document.createEventObject(); evObj.ctrlKey=true; fireOnThis.fireEvent('onclick', evObj); } 
}
```